# Creating an iterator that either steps upwards or downwards

Tags: rust

I'd ideally like to have something like the following:

```
iter = if go_up {
  (min .. limit)
} else {
  (limit .. max).rev()
};
```

to create an iterator that either counts up or down to some limit, depending on the situation. However, because `Range` and `Rev` are different types, I can't do this. I can use the `step_by` feature, but because my limits are an unsigned data-type, I then also have to cast everything. The best I have so far is:

```
#![feature(step_by)]
iter = if go_up {
  (min as i64 .. limit as i64).step_by(1)
} else {
  (limit as i64 .. max as i64).step_by(-1)
};
```

but this requires both unstable features, and shoehorning my types. It seems like there should be a neater way to do this; does anyone know one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The direct solution is to simply create an iterator that can either count upwards or downwards. Use an `enum` to choose between the types:

```
use std::ops::Range;
use std::iter::Rev;

enum Foo {
    Upwards(Range<u8>),
    Downwards(Rev<Range<u8>>),
}

impl Foo {
    fn new(min: u8, limit: u8, max: u8, go_up: bool) -> Foo {
        if go_up {
          Foo::Upwards(min..limit)
        } else {
          Foo::Downwards((limit..max).rev())
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for Foo {
    type Item = u8;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        match *self {
            Foo::Upwards(ref mut i) => i.next(),
            Foo::Downwards(ref mut i) => i.next(),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    for i in Foo::new(1, 5, 10, true) { 
        println!("{}", i);
    }

    for i in Foo::new(1, 5, 10, false) { 
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

Another pragmatic solution that introduces a little bit of indirection is to `Box` the iterators:

```
fn thing(min: u8, limit: u8, max: u8, go_up: bool) -> Box<Iterator<Item = u8>> {
    if go_up {
      Box::new(min..limit)
    } else {
      Box::new((limit..max).rev())
    }
}

fn main() {
    for i in thing(1, 5, 10, true) { 
        println!("{}", i);
    }

    for i in thing(1, 5, 10, false) { 
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

Comment: if the Iterator does not need to be returned from a function, the second solution can also be done with a reference: [playground](http://is.gd/wkGZVp). The inconvenience is that `&Iterator` (unlike `Box<Iterator>`) does not `impl Iterator`

Answer (score 2):

Personally, your solution

```
iter = if go_up {
  (min as i64 .. limit as i64).step_by(1)
} else {
  (limit as i64 .. max as i64).step_by(-1)
};
```

is a better option than Shepmaster's first example, since it's more complete (eg. there's a `size_hint`), it's more likely to be correct by virtue of being a standard tool and it's faster to write.

It's true that this is unstable, but there's nothing stopping you from just copying [the source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter.rs.html#3139-3142) in the meantime. That gives you a nice upgrade path for when this eventually gets stabilized.

The `enum` wrapper technique is great in more complex cases, though, but in this case I'd be tempted to KISS.

Comment: Ugh, `size_hint`. I always forget to forward that. I really need to write a `delegate_trait` compiler magic...